# NHibernate Group By // Having Issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by

I'll first expose what i want to do, and after explain my problem.
I've 2 tables : "CharItem" and "Attribute", and a table "ItemAttribute" to link both as it's a m:n relation. This table can also define a value for the attribute.

I wanted to search all items having at least some attributes. The sql query is this :

```
SELECT  ci.*
FROM     CharItem ci 
INNER JOIN ItemAttribute ia
on ci.CharItemId = ia.CharItemId 
WHERE 
( 
(ia.AttributeId = 48 and ia.ValueX >= 1) 
or (ia.AttributeId = 6) 
) 
GROUP BY ci.CharItemId 
HAVING   count(ia.AttributeId) >= 2
```

So as you can see, what i want is to find all items, so my query must 
return me some item objects.

I've tryied to do it, and i think i've almost find the solution, but 
i'm missing something. With the following method, i return the good 
ids, but not a full item, and i don't find how to get a full item :x

```
  var query = Session 
  .CreateCriteria(typeof(CharItem), "ci") 
  .CreateCriteria("ci.ItemAttribute", "ia", JoinType.InnerJoin); 
  Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction(); 
  foreach (var entry in itemAttribs) 
  { 
    var attribute = entry.Key; 
    var sign = entry.Value.Item1; 
    var value = entry.Value.Item2; 
    var restrictAttrib = Restrictions.Eq("ia.Attribute", attribute); 
    Conjunction conjunction =Restrictions.Conjunction(); 
    conjunction.Add(restrictAttrib); 
    conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ia.Value", values[j])); 
    disjunction.Add(conjunction); 
  } 
  query.Add(disjunction); 
  query.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList() 
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("ci.CharItemId"),"CharItemid")); 
  query.Add(Restrictions.Ge(Projections.Count("ia.Attribute"), itemAttribs.Count)); 
} 
var charItems = query.List<CharItem>();
```

Thanks for your help.

Solved! Check answers to see how to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a heads up, check out the edit I made to see how to get syntax highlighting in your code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Projections, NHibernate will return only the properties specified in the projection. That's why you get only the ids back in the above case. If you want all the other attributes of item, you need to explicitly add them to the list of projections.

Comment: I've tryed to had all properties of my object, but i still get an error : "The value \"System.Object[]\" is not of type \"MulesOrganizerModel.EntityClasses.CharItem\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value"

Comment: you have to use a resulttransformer to transform the object array to a list of CharItem

Comment: In fact still got a problem :x It works fine for several cases, but the ItemAttributes linked to my item object are not loaded when i call the property (an item can have several itemAttributes)